# How do I list the duration of videos in a youtube list one by one?

Tags: excel, list, youtube, playlist

There is a list that I am not creating the list. I want to export the name and duration of each video in this list to excel or anywhere. It would be nice if I could copy the links of videos as well, but it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)#[contentDetails.duration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration).

Indeed by retrieving the JSON at https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=VIDEO_ID&key=API_KEY you would get for example for [`jNQXAC9IVRw`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw):

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "yBF8nDhbRsQIALYRMSY1W9dtIPM",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "-gM2wTC3rW9_yfOtoOD4fcaQvl4",
      "id": "jNQXAC9IVRw",
      "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT19S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "sd",
        "caption": "true",
        "licensedContent": true,
        "contentRating": {},
        "projection": "rectangular"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but very complicated